Kentico 13 Net8.0 debug issue "System.TypeLoadException"
I am currently migrating a huge project from kentico 12 (.Net FGramework 4.8 MVC) to K13 (.Net8.0 MVC) and I have a really odd problem:

If I did any modifictaion on source code build and start a debug session, it works as expected.
If I start a new debug session without any modification on source code, I have an System.TypeLoadException: "Method 'get_ApplicationInstance' in type 'CMS.AspNetCore.Platform.HttpContextImpl' from assembly 'CMS.AspNetCore.Platform, Version=13.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9' does not have an implementation.'

The exception
To circonvent this issue, I added a dummy Console.WriteLine(....) that I Comment/Uncomment beetwen each debug session. But it is not really convenient...
how I handled it

Rebuild do not fix the issue
Originaly I thought my system was the cause, but a full reinstall (Windows and VS) did not fix it either.

